# Library to work with XAdES digital signatures

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm looking for a library compatible with microsoft.net framework that allows the creation and verification of XAdES signatures (XAdES, XAdES-C, XAdES-XL, etc...).

It is important that the library enable the programmer to choose:

1.- Type of certificate to use in the signature process (PFX file, Windows centralized store, SmartCard)
2.- CRL to validate the certificate.
3.- Possibility to include Time stamping on the signature.
4.- Possibility to include OCSP response on the signature.

All I found are libraries in Java, but have not found any libraries in .NET.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems XAdES (XML Advances Digital Signature) is dificult to find :-D

I searched in the web but I only found implementations in Java using Apache libraries, and only 1 .NET library that is mentioned in some web forums:

SecureBlackbox by EldoS
http://www.eldos.com/sbb/

In the tests in ran on this library I found it to work perfectly with documents that only need 1 signature, but when you need to multi-sign a document it surfaces some problems.

At the moment I have not found a functional implementation of XAdES in .NET that you can use to put multiple signatures in an XML with Timestamping al CRLs.

**EDIT (27/08/2012):**

A team at Microsoft France developed an implementation of XAdES using .NET 3.5.

At this moment the library is available for download at this Microsoft web site ( http://www.microsoft.com/france/interop/ressources/xades.aspx) and it supports XAdES, XAdES-T, XAdES-C, XAdES-X and XAdES-XL signatures.

A pretty good solution entirely written in .NET

Comment: Did you contact our support? XAdES is complicated and maybe some adjustment of your code is needed to accomplish the task.

Comment: I evaluated a bit Microsoft.XAdES (it can still be found in archive) and unfortunately the code is horrible enough because it makes use of non public APIs in .NET framework components. This non public APIs is no more available in recent .NET implementations.

Answer (score 4):

At this moment, I'm in a team (with Víctor M. Villa) developing a library to provide XAdES support for the .NET Framework.

We've just released version 1.0, that provides early support for XAdES-BES, and we have soon in our Roadmap the inclusion os Countersignature and Cosignature.

Maybe the library can help you somehow. You can find it in [XAdES .NET Project](http://xadesnet.codeplex.com/)

It is compatible with NET 2.0 and 3.5.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll take a moment to look at this project, it seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the .NET XAdES Starting Kit developed by Microsoft France
(source provided under the FOSS license CeCILL-B):

- [Decrypt my World MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2012/05/25/net-and-the-xades-standard.aspx)
- [CeCILL-B license in english](http://www.cecill.info/licences/Licence_CeCILL-B_V1-en.txt)

Comment: Really interesting piece. I'll test the library, looks promising.