# How do I sign and verify MSFT Word XAdES-X-L documents?

Tags: c#, encryption, ms-word, cryptography, digital-signature

I need to sign and verify Microsoft Word documents that are signed with the XAdES-X-L format.

How can I use C# to create and verify such a signature?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the responses to the question [Library to work with XAdES digital signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859179/library-to-work-with-xades-digital-signatures)

It's a little outdated but the links to the libraries still work.