# How to Digitally sign XML Document in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a requirement to Sign an XML document, and am not sure where to start.

In a nutshell, we ( a utility company in Italy) must submit an xml doc (invoice copies) and the it must be signed with one of the following two signature formats:

> CAdES-BES   (CMS Advanced Electronic Signatures) with a structure compliant with the public specifications ETSI TS 101 733 V1.7.4, as provided for in the appropriate legislation starting from 1 September 2010,
>
> XAdES-BES (XML Advanced Electronic Signatures), with a structure compliant with the public specifications ETSI TS 101 903 version 1.4.1, as provided for in the appropriate legislation starting from 1 September 2010. The only method accepted for this type of signature is the “enveloped” method. In addition the XAdES signature must have the Reference element with URI=“” or with URI=“#iddoc” where iddoc is the identity code of the document to be signed: the URI attribute cannot be omitted from the Reference elements.

This is the [full spec](https://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/en/c-12.htm)

Is there a c# library or tool to help get this done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706020

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859179

Comment: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/cades_bes.asp

Comment: https://github.com/ctt-gob-es/FirmaXadesNet

Comment: Seems there's plenty of prior art.  I just googled "CAdES-BES c#" and "XAdES-BES".

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you so much for helping me get going with this.